# How to avoid the backslash that is getting appended in spark df

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have created the below dataframes and while saving it as a JSON, the backslash are getting appended. How to avoid it?

df2=df1.withColumn("details",F.struct("id1","id2")).withColumn("result",F.struct("time","dist")).select("details","result")

df3=df2.withColumn("step1",F.struct("details","result"))

df4= df3.withColumn("value",F.struct("step1"))

df5=df4.withColumn ("type",F.lit("START")).select("values","value")

df5.write.format("json").mode("overwrite").option("delimiter",",").option("quote","").save("/home/usr/test1.json")

#{"type":"start", "values":{"step1":{"details":{"id1":"es1","id2":"d455"},"result":{"time":6785467578, "dist":7.95" }}}}

#Ouput:{ "type":"start", "values":{"step1":"{"details":"id1":"es1", "id2": "d455"},"result":{"time":6785467578, "dist":7.95"}}"}}